# Remove socket connection

Tags: java, sockets

I have a problem with removing socket connection. I'm using :

```
socket.close();
```

but when I try to open another socket connection from the same process, I get this error :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Where am I going wrong, thanks by advance.

Comment: Hard to say. Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the server you were connected to has closed its listening socket.

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem